# ServiceStack.Text: JsConfig changes done after serializing some objects not picked up

Tags: c#, json, serialization, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack.Text as the default serializer within my services.

Today I came across an unexpected issue where:

- after one of the services did some JsConfig configuration of the
  serializer
- and the serializer was used (i.e. objects were serialized and deserialized)
- another service called later tried adding its custom configuration on top of that but the configuration was ignored.

If the custom configuration of service2 was moved up a level and done before the serializer was used, then everything worked as expected.

Does that mean that:

- the configuration can be done only on AppStart or cannot be overwritten once the serializer is in use?
- or is the configuration cached maybe somewhere once the serializer is used? If so, can the cache be forced to refresh itself?

Can you think of anything else that would be causing that sort of issue?

I'm using version 3.9.35 consistently in every service.
All 3 services are WebApi projects.

I wrote a very simple console app that demonstrates the issue:

```
namespace SerializationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = new Foo() {Id = "abcdef", Type = "standardFoo"};
            var bar = new Bar() {Color = "red", Number = 10};

            JsConfig<Foo>.IncludeTypeInfo = true;

            var serializedFoo = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(foo);
            var serializedBar = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(bar);

            var deserializedFoo = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Foo>(serializedFoo);
            var deserializedBar = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Bar>(serializedBar);

            JsConfig<Foo>.IncludeTypeInfo = false;
            JsConfig<Bar>.IncludeTypeInfo = true;

            var serializedFoo2 = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(foo);
            var serializedBar2 = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(bar);

            var deserializedFoo2 = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Foo>(serializedFoo2);
            var deserializedBar2 = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Bar>(serializedBar2);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of trying to Negate the IncludeTypeInfo property. Use the ExcludeTypeInfo.**

Take a look at the internal class WriteType. In order to determine whether to include the type in serialization it checks a few things.

First it checks all four static bool properties. There are general JsConfig values and Type specific values. General will overall the type specifics because of the logical "OR"

```
private static bool IsIncluded
{
    get
    {
        return (JsConfig.IncludeTypeInfo || JsConfig<T>.IncludeTypeInfo);
    }
}
private static bool IsExcluded
{
    get
    {
        return (JsConfig.ExcludeTypeInfo || JsConfig<T>.ExcludeTypeInfo);
    }
}
```

Then there is this method in

```
private static bool ShouldSkipType() { return IsExcluded && !IsIncluded; }
```

So you will see in order to skip both Exclude and Include must pass the test. Not sure why it was designed this way but that's how it currently works.